tokens available in an email
Am creating an email to all members past and present. There are no membership tokens available from the tokens dropdown. Does that mean I cannot use ones related to membership? I want to display their curent membership status and expiry date. I have tried them as: {membership.status} and expiry date: {membership.end_date} (kinda guessing what the toekn is) but they don't seem to work. I am testing with a membership created through the TEST function which I thought would show up as a member (even although a test membership).
If the above tokens cannot be used - what is the easiest way for people to check if they are a member or not? (we don't currently have members logging in as there isn't really a need, but could a OTP be generated with this mailout email so they can check it?)

Most organizations have a simple concept of membership that can reasonably ask the question "what is so-and-so's expiry date"? But CiviCRM's concept of membership is more sophisticated in that it doesn't preclude having more than one membership per person (also supporting different membership types). So a token associated with "current membership status for this contact" isn't as well defined as you might assume. The fuzion token makes what is probably a reasonable guess for most organizations.

Try using Fuzion token, they have lots of tokens which can be used on Non-membership emails.

If you start by doing a search for memberships (eg Search > Find Memberships) and then send a mail you will find a load of membership tokens.
If you have a list of memberships then it is simple to say for each one what the status or end date is.  If you have a list of contacts, they could have multiple memberships so what would a token for 'end_date' produce?  In practice, you generally only have one current membership so a custom token for 'end_date' could look for a current membership and return its end_date - but you still need to handle multiples (eg choose a specific membership type, or the soonest-expiring, or even return a list of end_dates).
